# What is the best way to test if data is normally distributed?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, matlab, visualization

I have two samples $X_1 \; (N= 97)$ and $X_2 \; (N=4782)$ drawn from the same population data. I like to test (using Statistical Visualizations such as `normplot` and `qqplot`, and Hypothesis Tests such as `jbtest`, `chi2gof`, and `kstest` in MATLAB) if the data from each sample is normally distributed.

My First Data is

```
    X = [8.13010235400000,13.6713071300000,14.0362434700000,18.4349488200000,26.5650511800000,30.9637565300000,34.3803447200000,40.6012946500000,45,49.3987053500000,58.6713071300000,59.0362434700000,59.0362434700000,59.0362434700000,61.9275130600000,61.9275130600000,63.4349488200000,63.4349488200000,63.4349488200000,63.4349488200000,63.4349488200000,64.4400348300000,71.5650511800000,71.5650511800000,71.5650511800000,71.5650511800000,75.9637565300000,75.9637565300000,75.9637565300000,75.9637565300000,75.9637565300000,75.9637565300000,75.9637565300000,75.9637565300000,75.9637565300000,75.9637565300000,77.4711922900000,77.4711922900000,77.4711922900000,77.4711922900000,77.4711922900000,77.4711922900000,77.4711922900000,77.4711922900000,77.4711922900000,78.6900675300000,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,93.1798301200000,97.1250163500000,97.7651660200000,102.528807700000,102.528807700000,102.528807700000,102.528807700000,102.528807700000,104.036243500000,104.036243500000,104.036243500000,104.036243500000,104.036243500000,104.036243500000,104.036243500000,105.255118700000,108.434948800000,108.434948800000,108.434948800000,108.434948800000,109.440034800000,116.565051200000,118.072486900000,120.963756500000,127.746805400000,130.601294600000,135,137.489552900000,139.398705400000,139.398705400000,149.036243500000,153.434948800000,159.227745300000,161.565051200000,179.999998800000,180];
```

The analyses using statistical visualizations in MATLAB, shows that the underlying distribution for both samples are normal. However, from the hypothesis tests, the null hypothesis for the $X_1$ sample is not rejected using the same significance value (except for the chi-square test), but that for the $X_2$ is completely rejected.

I am now confused as to how to prove my samples are normally distributed and as well come from the same population data. Please, what can I do in this situation?

**PS :** Sample $X_2$ is too large for me to post, but if there is any suggestion on how I could show this, then I don’t mind.

Attaching Image
[image]

Comment: Okay! i'll do that just now. Thank you very much.

Comment: IMHO this question is appropriate here. We have an active 'statistics' tag. Perhaps users who are more familiar with that tag are better qualified to give advice about its use.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a Shapiro-Wilk Test. Let

$$H_0 : \text{ the data is normally distributed}$$

$$H_a : \text{ the data is not normally distributed}$$

R statistical software gives

```
x<-c(8.13010235400000,13.6713071300000,14.0362434700000,18.4349488200000,26.5650511800000,30.9637565300000,34.3803447200000,40.6012946500000,45,49.3987053500000,58.6713071300000,59.0362434700000,59.0362434700000,59.0362434700000,61.9275130600000,61.9275130600000,63.4349488200000,63.4349488200000,63.4349488200000,63.4349488200000,63.4349488200000,64.4400348300000,71.5650511800000,71.5650511800000,71.5650511800000,71.5650511800000,75.9637565300000,75.9637565300000,75.9637565300000,75.9637565300000,75.9637565300000,75.9637565300000,75.9637565300000,75.9637565300000,75.9637565300000,75.9637565300000,77.4711922900000,77.4711922900000,77.4711922900000,77.4711922900000,77.4711922900000,77.4711922900000,77.4711922900000,77.4711922900000,77.4711922900000,78.6900675300000,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,93.1798301200000,97.1250163500000,97.7651660200000,102.528807700000,102.528807700000,102.528807700000,102.528807700000,102.528807700000,104.036243500000,104.036243500000,104.036243500000,104.036243500000,104.036243500000,104.036243500000,104.036243500000,105.255118700000,108.434948800000,108.434948800000,108.434948800000,108.434948800000,109.440034800000,116.565051200000,118.072486900000,120.963756500000,127.746805400000,130.601294600000,135,137.489552900000,139.398705400000,139.398705400000,149.036243500000,153.434948800000,159.227745300000,161.565051200000,179.999998800000,180)

shapiro.test(x)

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  x
W = 0.96484, p-value = 0.01061
```

Since $0.01061<0.05$ we have significant evidence at $\alpha=0.05$ to reject the null hypothesis and conclude that the data is non-normal.

A Q-Q Plot supports our conclusion:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Remy. Please take a look at the figures i posted for both data. Looking at the graphical plot for the X2 data, can you say it isnt normally distributed?

Answer (score 2):

**Graphical methods.** First, some general comments. Graphical methods include:

- making a histogram
  on a density scale and then overlaying a normal curve with $\mu = \bar X$ and
  $\sigma^2 = S^2,$ where $\bar X$ and $S^2$ are the sample mean and variance
  respectively,
- plotting an empirical CDF of the data along with the CDF
  of the normal distribution (as above),
- making a 'normal probability plot'
  (also called a 'normal Q-Q plot') to see if points lie mainly along a
  straight line.

Especially for large samples, such graphical descriptions of the data can
give a good idea whether the data may have been randomly sampled from 
a normal population. But they do not provide formal statistical goodness-of-fit (GOF) tests.

Thank you for providing your first dataset. I used it to make the histogram
and ECDF plots below. While I have been working on this, @Remy(+1) has provided
an normal probability plot, so I'll skip that.

[image]

My impression is that these data have tails that are 'too fat' to have
come from a normal population.

**Formal GOF tests.** A very good GOF test is the Shapiro-Wilk test implemented in R statistical
software. It tests the null hypothesis that the data fit *some* normal
distribution against the alternative that they do not. Failure to reject
the null hypothesis is not the same thing as a guarantee that the parent
population is normal. Rejection is a good indication that the data depart
in some important way from what one expects of a random sample from a normal
population. Generally speaking, given a sufficiently large real-world sample, the Shapiro-Wilk
test will reject, because *precisely* normal data are rare in practice and
a large sample makes it easier to find the flaws (possibly unimportant ones).

@Remy also shows a Shapiro-Wilk test, with results not consistent with normality.
I get the same result, and will not post my result.

As implemented in most software, the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test uses the null
hypothesis that the data fit *a particular* normal distribution. Consequently,
if $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ must be estimated by $\bar X$ and $S^2,$ the probability
theory behind the K-S test is not quite correct (larger errors for smaller
samples).

*Notes:* (1) You mention the 'jbtest' and 'chi2gof'. I am not sure exactly what
these tests are. I suppose 'kstest' must be some form of the K-S test, but I
don't know whether it tests against *any normal distribution* or *a specific normal distribution.* (2) Thank you for providing data for your first sample.
I have provided a histogram and an ECDF plot. (Also, confirmed the @remy's normal probability plot and result from the Shapiro-Wilk test.)

Comment: Thank you @BruceET. Please take a look at: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/336502/how-to-combine-probability-plots-and-hypothesis-tests-to-check-normality?noredirect=1#comment636128_336502 for images of my qqplot and plots comparing the empirical cdf V the normal cdf of both X and X2. Your ecdf plot look a bit strange compared to mine. Could you please kindly comment or make inferences based on my plots above? Thank you very much.

Comment: One difference is that the ECDF plot puts the data values on the horizontal axis, whereas R's default for Q-Q Plots is to put data values on the vertical axis (presumably to coordinate with vertical box-plots). Another is that Q-Q plots distort the 'theoretical' axis so that normal data will tend to fall in a straight line. // Either way, most of your data are btw about 55 and about 110, with many straggling outliers making longer-than-normal tails.

Comment: It is OK if you want to take advice to move a Question from one site to another. But if you do, you should remove it from the first site. I have no disagreement with the Answ by Nick Cox's on the Stat site. // An important diff btw his Q-Q plot and @Remy's here is the position of the reference line, which can be plotted in several different ways.

Comment: Ok. Thank you @BruceET.